# How to create page borders using Apache POI in excel files with Java?

Tags: java, excel, format, apache-poi

I have been using Apache POI to create excel invoices/reports in my application.
The report uses cell styles which have different foreground and background colors, different font sizes, bordered cells and non-bordered cells. A new requirement needs me to put page borders. I have gone through most of the [samples](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html). I could only find sample code for cell level borders and not the page as a whole.

In OpenOffice/Libre Office excel applications this can be achieved by going to Format>Page>Border and selecting options as in the image below

[page border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3IeX.png)

I thank you all in advance.

Comment: Microsoft Excel cannot do this. Libreoffice Calc and Openoffice Calc can. But if you save in Calc as `*.xlsx` format, then the page border lines will not be saved. So there is not a place in `*.xlsx` for saving page border lines. Saved as `*.ods` the page border lines will be saved, but `apache-poi` is **not** supposed to deal with `*.ods` files.

Comment: @AxelRichter First off I thank you for the effort and time you spent, but I was able to save an `*.xlsx` with page borders with Libreoffice calc application. It was the reason, I lthought it would be possible to emulate it with `apace-poi`

Comment: "but I was able to save an `*.xlsx` with page borders with Libreoffice calc application.": And if you reopen this `*.xlsx` file, the page border line formats are still there? That would be magic because there is really not a place for storing  page border line formats in `*.xlsx`.

Comment: @AxelRichter I am sorry for sounding silly. You are right. I had earlier created an "xlsx" file, set the page borders and saved it using "Save as" option to another "xlsx" file using Libre Office calc. The title showed the new file name and I assumed, the application has saved the file and loaded the new file. I was able to see the page borders in page preview. I did this couple of times, but never closed the file and re-opened it.  

After your comment, when I closed the file and re-opened it the page border was missing, silly on my part.